# Background Image Slideshow Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, background-image

I'm trying to set up a sideshow like it's done on this site: http://www.vvvterschelling.nl/

My questions are:

1. How do I actualize the sideshow in the background linked with the one in the site header?
2. How to get this nice blur and fadeout effect around the corner of the background image?

Comment: the best would be to use a plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/slideshow

Comment: ehm ... ok ... I think you missed the question. Of course I'am searching  for a plugin! To be more specific: Does anyone know a plugin which can do this effect? Essential ist the linked Slideshow in the background and in the site header!

Comment: i think they are using custom library. Just check by your firebug Net Panel

Answer (score 0):

Fading with 2 images needs 2 DIVs. You got one displayed DIV, then fadeIn new one over it, or fadeOut old one over new one. Header and background are made using same technique, but probably using IMG tag, since it is resizable. To make it work together, just use:

```
$('#newHeader, #newBackground').fadeIn();
```

Blur of background is prepared before in a graphics program, like Photoshop or something.